# Вытянуть из базы определенные записи mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

```
В таблице tovaru есть атрибут customer, в нем записи повторяются например 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3
как вывести эти записи по одном экземпляру например только 1, 2, 3 средствами php
много вариантов перепробывал ниодин не помог
```

Answer (score 1):

В пару строчек.

```
$mass = explode (",", $znachenie_polya_iz_bazy);
$result = array_unique ($mass);
```

Comment: должен ведь быть еще и запрос типа SELECT customer FROM tovaru WHERE

Comment: Ну да, должен. Ну это сами, нет времени ;)

Comment: 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3 а это отдельные строки в таблице или это целая строка?
если отдельные строки то Вам поможет добавление в sql запрос параметра group by customer.